# How to replicate data in one Hadoop cluster to another Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Apache Hadoop. We have one Hadoop cluster[1] filled with some data. And there's another Hadoop cluster[2] empty with data. What is the simplest and most preferred way to replicate data from [1] into [2] ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use DistCp (Distributed copy), It is a tool to allow you copy data between clusters or from/to a different file system like S3 or FTP server.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp2.html

You must specify the absolute path to copy data from external cluster: hdfs://OtherClusterNN:port/path

This tool launch a MapReduce job that copy data in parallel from any kind of source available in Hadoop FileSystem library like HDFS, FTP, S3, AZURE(in latest versions, etc)

To copy data from different versions of hadoop, instead to use HDFS protocol, you must use HftpFileSystem from one of them.

Comment: In this way.. Don't we need to worry about any internal configs of 2 servers (ex: no of nodes) and the table structures etc.??

Comment: The communication with HDFS always start with the NameNode, the host in the URL (hdfs://NameNode:port/path). THe NameNode is who keep the track of all available Data Nodes in the cluster and the location of each HDFS block. You don´t need to deal with that by hand. After the client receive the location of each block it will be able to contact directly the Data Nodes to retrieve the data.

Comment: But if your both clusters have a different HDFS versions, then both cluster won´t be able to comunnicate, HDFS versions don´t warranty backward compatibility. The solution in this case is to use HftpFileSystem  to read from the source since this API is only for read. This API warranty compatibility between versions

Comment: Could you please add the command I need to enter to move data?

Comment: this only works for offline data, what do we do with online data?